# Regular expression should not match a specific word with all possibilities

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

My expression should not match a specific word which is "COUNTY" and gives you an error. I have a regular expression as

```
*[^\s].*[^(!?.*!?county|!?County|!?COUNTY)$.*]
```

which doesn't work properly.
This is my regular expression

```
*[^\s].*[^(!?.*!?county|!?County|!?COUNTY)$.*]
```

but it gives me an error when the string is test1 county but not for county test1, test1 county test2

Valid string:

1. LAs Vegas parkway or empty string/no data

Invalid string

1. County Las vegas Parkway
2. Las vegas county Parkway
3. Las vegas parkway COUNTY

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
((.*)(?:COUNTY|County|county)(.*)?)
```

And call group $2$3

See this link: https://regex101.com/r/HgC3DG/1

**OR**

Use

```
(.*)(?:COUNTY|County|county)(.*)?
```

And call group $1$2

See link: https://regex101.com/r/HgC3DG/2

**For XSD use this:**

```
^((?!County)(?!COUNTY)(?!county).)*$
```

See link: https://regex101.com/r/gfd0DK/1

Comment: The expression is givining an error at sysmbol ? and The error - Expression is not a valid XML regular expression.

Comment: I am using XSD and XML to validate the data.

Comment: Then check this might work for you: `^((?!County)(?!COUNTY)(?!county).)*$`

Comment: Yes I tried My xml validator is givving me an error at sysmbol ? from your given code..when I switched the sysmbols ^((!?County)(!?COUNTY)(!?county).)*$ the expression was valid but the input string doesnt accept for example if i give Test1 it should validate but having an error

Comment: can you please update your question by adding your actual XML example with tags and values?

Comment: This is my input field in xml :<County>test1</County>

Comment: XSD  <xs:simpleType name="CountyName">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:minLength value="1"/>
   <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
   <xs:pattern value="(.*[^\s].*)(!?:COUNTY|County|county)(.*[^\s].*)?"/>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>